# How do I modify a .html file to give hardcoded inputs to input fields every time?

Tags: arguments, html, powerschool

I want to access my Powerschool (powerschool.avon.k12.ct.us), and I find the need to type in my password and username every time rather tedious. To try and fix this I downloaded the page's source in Chrome, below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0052)http://powerschool.avon.k12.ct.us/guardian/home.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Parent Sign In</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<link href="./Powerschool_files/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="./Powerschool_files/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style> 
<script language="JavaScript" src="./Powerschool_files/md5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
var pskey = "4EDE156E2FAD0F1A427D2AD066530F496ADC3EEA78CE43E70F28053576FD4EA1";
//-->
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function deleteCookie(cookieName){
    var cookieDate = new Date();
    cookieDate.setTime(cookieDate.getTime()-1);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=; expires='" + cookieDate.toGMTString()+"'; path=/";
}
deleteCookie("InformAuthToken");

function getURLParameter(name) {
    return unescape(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide or show the translator login input field
    // if the URL parameter "translator" is present
    var translator = getURLParameter("translator");
    if (translator == "null") {
        $j('#translatorInput').hide();
    } else {
        if (translator == "true") {
            $j('#translatorInput').show();
        } else {
            $j('#translatorInput').hide();
        }
    }
    $j('a.popWin').click(function(){
        var winURL = $j(this).attr('href');
        window.open(winURL);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="pslogin" id="palogin">
<div id="container">
     <div id="branding-powerschool"><img src="./Powerschool_files/ps7-logo-lrg.png" alt="PowerSchool" width="280" height="41"></div>
  <div id="content" class="group">
<form action="./Powerschool_files/Powerschool.htm" method="post" name="LoginForm" target="_top" id="LoginForm" onsubmit="doPCASLogin(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="pstoken" value="2465670387a1nxrEimrKqPMN0c7QbxxKLNZe16PRC">
  <input type="hidden" name="contextData" value="4EDE156E2FAD0F1A427D2AD066530F496ADC3EEA78CE43E70F28053576FD4EA1">
  <input type="hidden" name="dbpw" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="translator_username" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="translator_password" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="translator_ldappassword" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="serviceName" value="PS Parent Portal">
<input type="hidden" name="serviceTicket" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pcasServerUrl" value="/">
<input type="hidden" name="credentialType" value="User Id and Password Credential">







              <h2>Parent Sign In</h2>
      <!--box content-->

    <div id="noscript" class="feedback-alert" style="display: none;"> To sign in to PowerSchool, you must use a browser that supports and has JavaScript enabled. </div>
    <fieldset id="login-inputs" class="group">

        <div>
              <label>Username</label>
              <input type="text" id="fieldAccount" name="account" value="" size="39">
        </div>
        <div>
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="pw" value="" size="39"><div id="login-help"><a href="http://powerschool.avon.k12.ct.us/public/logonhelp.html">Having trouble signing in?</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="translatorInput" style="display: none;">
              <label>Translator Sign In</label>
              <input type="password" name="translatorpw" value="" size="39">
        </div>
        <div class="button-row">
        <button type="submit" id="btn-enter" title="Sign In To PowerSchool Parent Access" value="Enter" border="0">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset> 

      <!-- box content-->


</form>


 </div>
 <div id="footer" class="group">
    <p>Copyright© 2005 - 2013 Pearson Education, Inc., or its affiliate(s). All rights reserved.</p>
    <p id="pearsoncorplink"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/powerschool" class="popWin fb" title="Join us on Facebook">Join us on Facebook</a></p>
</div>

</div>
<div id="branding-pearson">
    <div id="logo-pearson"></div>
    <div id="tagline-pearson"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * Set the page's locale via a request_locale URL parameter. If there is already a URL parameter by
     * this name, then substitute it with the passed-in locale. NOTE: This function will actually cause the page
     * to be re-submitted with the new locale, so it really should not be used with pages submitted via POST
     * requests (if there are any, which I hope there are not).
     * @param locale the locale to set (e.g. en_US)
     */
    function setPageLocale (locale) {
      var c=String (window.location);
      var rlpos = c.indexOf("request_locale=");
      var afterPart = "";
      if (rlpos > 0) {
        var afterBegin = c.indexOf("&", rlpos);
        if (afterBegin > 0) {
          afterPart = c.substring(afterBegin);
        }
        c = c.substring(0, rlpos-1);
      }
      var s=(c.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?');
      var np = c + s + 'request_locale=' + locale + afterPart;
      window.location = np;
    }

    function jsCheck() {
            document.getElementById("login-inputs").className = 'group';

    }
 jsCheck();
</script>

<script>
$j('#noscript').hide();
function jsEnabled() {
    if(typeof $j != 'function'){
        alert('Developer: This page is missing key components required for functionality!\n\nPossible causes include:\n - Commonscripts might be missing.\n - Page customization might enabled, and incomplete.');
        //document.write('<script...');
        } else {
        $j('#login-inputs').removeClass('hide');
        $j("#fieldAccount").focus();
    }
}
$j(document).ready(function(){
    jsEnabled();
});

</script>


</body></html>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to directly modify the downloaded source to automatically fill the input boxes (the below block is where I think it would be done) to always fill in the username and pass fields with "myUsername" and "myPassword," or something like that. I tried setting the value of the Input and Username fields, but that (chrome) gave me an, shown here:

```
No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Powerschool_files/Powerschool.htm
```

`Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.`

Do you guys know how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the entire page, it's probably simpler to make a bookmarklet that fills in the form.  Just edit a normal bookmark and change the link to be this:

```
javascript:(function() { document.forms[0].elements[0].value="hi" })()
```

That will set the value of the first field in the first form. (It may take some experimenting to see which form number and which field number.)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Chrome to remember your passwords for you automatically, but what you have should actually work.  You just need to change any paths to urls for it to work perfectly.  One that you definitely need to change is the form `action`:

```
- ./Powerschool_files/Powerschool.htm
+ https://example.com/Powerschool_files/Powerschool.htm
```

This should allow you to submit directly to that site unless they have a CSRF token in the form that I don't see.

Comment: Example.com? Should that be the address of the site?

Comment: When I modify it to the correct value chrome opens it up with the path to the file in the address bar. When I click submit the page refreshes and goes to the actual webpage, with blank fields. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 no; I think your form action is still incorrect